# Query giving error when using 'key' column

Tags: mysql

this query is giving me an error when I add the `key` column, any help?

`username` and `product` are composite primary key, just in case.

```
mysql> select * from sw_product_session where username='admin';
+----------+----------+------------+----------------------------+
| username | product  | expire     | key                        |
+----------+----------+------------+----------------------------+
| admin    | printbox | 1373550885 | 2ijm77cpnfc7miktasopkik2q2 |
+----------+----------+------------+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from sw_product_session where username='admin' AND product='printbox';
+----------+----------+------------+----------------------------+
| username | product  | expire     | key                        |
+----------+----------+------------+----------------------------+
| admin    | printbox | 1373550885 | 2ijm77cpnfc7miktasopkik2q2 |
+----------+----------+------------+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from sw_product_session where username='admin' AND product='printbox' AND key='2ijm77cpnfc7miktasopkik2q2';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key='2ijm77cpnfc7miktasopkik2q2'' at line 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to remember that any [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) need to be escaped:

```
AND `key`='...'
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem.